# Transparency over image to prevent copying

Tags: html

Will this method of placing a transparency over an image prevent Google copying it
Or will it just find the image from the uncrypted code above (image.png)
Am I wasting my time using this method of masking the image to fool Google

Comment: See Google's answer to your question. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en :)

Answer (score -1):

**For quick removal**

Use the [Remove URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419) tool. You should see results fairly quickly.

**For non-emergency image removal**

To prevent images from your site appearing in Google's search results, add a robots.txt file to the root of the server that blocks the image. It takes longer to remove an image from search results than the Remove URLs tool, but is an Internet standard that applies to all search engines, and you have more flexible control through the use of wildcards or subpath blocking.

For example, if you want Google to exclude the dogs.jpg image that appears on your site at www.yoursite.com/images/dogs.jpg, add the following to your robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /images/dogs.jpg
```

The next time Google crawls your site, we'll see this directive and drop your image from our search results.

To remove all the images on your site from our index, place the following robots.txt file in your server root:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /
```

Additionally, Google has introduced increased flexibility to the robots.txt file standard through the use asterisks. Disallow patterns may include "*" to match any sequence of characters, and patterns may end in "$" to indicate the end of a name. To remove all files of a specific file type (for example, to include .jpg but not .gif images), you'd use the following robots.txt entry:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /*.gif$
```

By specifying Googlebot-Image as the User-agent, the images will be excluded from Google Image Search. It will also prevent cropping of the image for display within Mobile Image Search, as the image will be completely removed from Google's Image index. If you would like to exclude the images from all Google searches (including Google web search and Google Images), specify User-agent Googlebot.

Comment: Copied without regret from [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en)

Comment: Why the downvote though? OP can't mark answered without an answer.